# Possible German translation

Tags: translation, blackletter

I'm having difficulty trying to make out the German at the bottom of this photo.  It's particularly hard to read because of the god-awful font.  My limited German can't even begin to guess at some of the letters.

All I can make out is "aus den" and the last bit which is something like "in the Kansas region".

The photo comes from an article talking about the history of Kansas when it was just a territory, circa 1855.

Can anybody (a)make out what the original German is, and (b) provide a translation?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read

> Plakat aus den Parteikämpfen im Kansasgebiete

which I would translate to

> Poster from the party struggles in the Kansas area.

Another translation, suggested by guidot in the comment, is

> Poster from the election campaign in the Kansas area.

The word *Parteikampf* is not longer used in current German. Translating it as "party struggle" draws an analogy from *Klassenkampf* ("class struggle"), while "election campaign" draws the analogy to "*Wahlkampf*" ("election campaign", literally).

Comment: *Parteikämpfe* may better translate to *election campaigns*.

Comment: @guidot Thanks for that useful piece of information. I amended my answer accordingly. I think, it is quite an improvement.

Comment: Ugg, I was way off base.  I thought that initial letter on 'Plaket' and  'Parteikämpfen' was either a 'B' or 'V'.  Would never have thought of it as a 'P'.  Terrible font!  Thanks, everyone!  Between that and the outdated vocabulary, no wonder I wasn't finding anything in my German dictionaries.   Thanks all.

Comment: The "terrible font" is simply Fraktur.

Comment: @Skrej: it has to be noted, that the descenders are somehow truncated in your picture, therefore the similarity to *V*.